# Range of logarithms

Tags: functions, logarithms

Given 
$$f(x)= \log_3\left(\log_.5(x^2+4x+4)\right)$$

I have to calculate the domain and  range of this function, i calculated the domain as $(-3,-1)-[-2]$

For the range I wrote the function as $\log_3(2)+\log_3\left(\log_.5(|x+2|)\right)$ but couldn't work it out any further.

Can anybody please give a hint on how should I proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $x^2+4x+4=(x+2)^2$ is $\mathbb R$ and the range $[0,\infty)$. $0$ is reached when $x=-2$.

Taking the logarithm, $-2\log_2|x+2|$ has the domain $\mathbb R\setminus\{-2\}$ and the range $\mathbb R$.

Taking the logarithm again, you must consider the part of the domain that achieves positive values of the previous expression,

$$-2\log_2|x+2|>0$$ or $$|x+2|<1,$$ indeed giving $$(-3,-1)\setminus\{-2\}$$ for the domain and $\mathbb R$ for the range.

Comment: Wolfram alpha is giving a maximum and minimum value so range can't be $R$

Comment: @Gem: you didn't read, WA gives a *numerical estimate* of the range, which is quite inaccurate. Check $f(-3)$ and $f(-2)$.

Comment: @Gem the range is $\mathbb{R}$ the function has no extrema. Derivative is $f'(x)=\dfrac{2}{2 (x+2) \log (3) \log (\left| x+2\right| )}\quad$. It's always nonzero. It's positive for $ -3<x<-2$ and negative for $-2<x<-1$

Answer (score 0):

**just hint**
$$\ln (x^2+4x+4)=\ln ((x+2)^2)$$
$$=2\ln (|x+2|) $$

$x $ is in the domain if
$$\ln (|x+2|)<0$$

or
$$0 <|x+2|<1$$ which gives

$$-1 <x+2 <1 \;\;\land x\ne -2$$
and finally
$$x\in (-3,-2)\cup (-2,-1) $$
when $x\to -2$, the function goes to $+\infty $.

Comment: I have used that to reach the final step that I have written in the question

Comment: @Gem: you are wrong.